# Python 3 CBC fail because of double backslash byte

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, byte, aes, cbc-mode

I am trying to read back ciphertext in a file, for example, `\t"\x87]\xb6^,\xa7G\xf7\x99<\xb2-\x06\xc8` however when I make it a bytearray for CBC decryption, I get `b'\\t"\\x87]\\xb6^,\\xa7G\\xf7\\x99<\\xb2-\\x06\\xc8'` which ultimately fails as this is not a 16 byte multiple for CBC to decrypt. I have tried decoding with unicode escape, however it doesn't retain it's data type as a byte. I cannot seem to work out how to get this to decrypt normally again?

Thanks.

Comment: This happens when you call `str()` on a bytes object (also implicitly, eg. in a `print()` call). It's not easily reverted, you should instead prevent this conversion from happening in the first place.

Comment: I fixed it. Using the "b" modifier in the open() statement on the file works, and skirts around every bytearray() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone with this issue:

If you are writing ciphertext to a file that contains a \, instead of reading it as a string and converting to bytes (which adds an extra \ escape character), use the "b" modifier in the open() statement.

Example: with open("test.txt","rb") - notice the b? That means everything from the file is automatically read as a byte. Don't write or deal with strings. Write and read bytes directly and then your encrypt/decrypt functions will now work. No extra \.